# creating a jar file in spring boot that is using command line runners

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

I have an application that is using command-line runners from spring-boot. When I want to build a **jar** package through

```
.\mvnw package
.\mvnw clean install
```

It just start the application instead of building the **.jar** as expected.
I have below plugin

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

The code is working fine but i need to use a jar file. How can i achieve that?

Comment: mvn package will create an executable jar that you will find in the target directory. It won't start the application same for mvn install it creates the jar and copy it in you local m2.

Comment: Its starting the application and in target folder there are classes only not jar file

Comment: No it doesn't start your application what you might see is your tests running that will launch the context but it doesn't start your application. If everything is successful then it create the jar in the target directory. In fact you have one .jar and .jar.original

Comment: This is correct only when commandline runner in excluded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you need run your test task, you need run "mvn clean package ", else run "mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true", jar file in your project root path  'target'

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [JEY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1976843/jey) It is running the unit test cases on context load after that jar file will be created. You may skip tests by "mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true"

Comment: `-Dmaven.test.skip` is not necessary, it is used to skip unit test but should not affect maven package lifecycle.